# Sitefinity Custom Widget - deploying external assembly

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity, sitefinity-feather, sitefinity-13

We are building a custom widget for Sitefinity. Looking at the options available we have chosen to go with the external MVC assembly approach to reduce dependencies. However, it appears that we still need to reference the custom widget assembly from the Sitefinity project in Visual Studio which would involve copying the assembly over, adding the reference and then redeploying Sitefinity.

What we would like to do is deploy the custom widget to Sitefinity without having to deploy the entire Sitefinity application, e.g. just upload the DLL through the Sitefinity user interface. Is this possible? If not, can we reference and deploy once and then just copy over new versions (and possibly have to restart Sitefinity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily **need** to reference the external assembly from the sitefinity project - as you said - you can just drop the dll in the bin folder and it should work.

But this external project - most probably, it will still need to reference one or more Sitefinity assemblies, so you will still need to add dependencies to it, e.g. via nuget.

**Edit**: Most probably you won't need to reference **all** sitefinity dlls, but you can install only the modules you need. This link lists the available nuget packages: https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/work-with-decoupled-modules#installing-the-all-modules-package-vs-the-light-package

I would start with **Progress.Sitefinity** instead of **Progress.Sitefinity.All**.

Then you build that class library and copy the output dll (e.g. MyCompanyCustom.dll) to the Sitefinity project. No need to copy the rest of the Sitefinity dlls, because they are already in the sitefinity project.

Just make sure that the Sitefinity assemblies that this external project references are the same version as the main site.

Comment: Thanks - so I just need to reference the same assemblies (13.x in our case) in a separate solution for the widget, build the solution and copy the relevant DLLs across to Sitefinity's bin. We can mock out the Sitefinity assemblies we use for easy local testing. Does that sound ok?

Comment: yes, correct - updated the answer above. Are you planning to reuse this widget without modifications in multiple projects? If no, then it would be much easier to just add it to the main SitefinityWebApp project.

Comment: No, just for one instance at current, but may be more later. Also, I want to avoid all the overhead of setting up and managing local Sitefinity development environments.

Comment: it's not such an overhead :) always good to have it local, so you can actually test your widget

Comment: I hear you - we are using the widget as a frame to an entire second application so the overhead of carrying SF along the way is clunky.  Thanks for all your help. Answer accepted.